# functions in actionscript (addChild)

Tags: function, actionscript, addchild

I've Just started learning actionscript 3.0, and I got a problem.
I just want a symbol to be in the stage for many times ,**not in a same time**, but it brings them all in at the beginning. I just used this piece of code below:

```
for (i=1,i<10,i++){
  stuff();
}
function stuff():void {
  theSymbol.x=(Math.random()*100);
  addChild("theSymbol");
}
```

Is there any other ways to :

1. Bring the symbol into the stage many times "not in a same time" ,in a while.
2. Call a function many times without using "for".

Thanks for any Ideas .PLZ answer soon as possible!
;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanna do something like:

```
setInterval(stuff, 1000) // call stuff() once every second.
function stuff():void {
   theSymbol.x=(Math.random()*100);
   addChild("theSymbol");
}
```

Does it helps you?

Comment: It was good.worked.But 2 questions:Can I change the "every second" thing?and making the 1000 ,infinity? @bribeiro

Comment: This 1000 is the interval between calls, not the amount of times that it will be called. If you don't use: clearInterval(yourInterval) it will keep calling the function every second forever.

Now if you change to setInterval(yourFunc, 2000) your function will be called every two seconds.